# Cannot get junit to work in eclipse after upgrade to windows 8.1

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-8, junit, windows-8.1

I have a junit test that works fine on my windows 7 Laptop. Though when I try to run the junit test on my desktop on 8.1 it just hangs, it all worked fine when the desktop was running windows 8.

I have 12 tests, though after I run the test the junit pane stays the same, 0/0
http://puu.sh/4TNvC

After 8 minutes of running the console shows this: 
 http://pastebin.com/U88h9bEv

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Debug: http://puu.sh/4TNvh

Comment: Perhaps Windows Firewall is blocking your connection? Try disabling it. I'd also suggest trying to run it as administrator

Comment: Do you, at some point in your test, connect to something on the internet?

Comment: No nothing in my test connects to the internet.

I hadn't thought of turning off firewalls etc, I disabled all security and ran as admin, still nothing.

Comment: I've tried installing JRE by itself, then JDK. I've also tried several different eclipse downloads.